# Creating multiple instance sharing common letter

Tags: python, class, oop

I want to create several instances for a class.
e.g.

```
class container():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

let's assume I want to make four instances sharing "C"

```
C1 = container()
C2 = container()
C3 = container()
C4 = container()
```

this would be the easiest way to make four instances but the code looks very ugly when there are many instances like this.

How can I write down the code that looks very neat?

Comment: use a list/dict as a way to collect and organize all instances, and make it easier to work with at the same time.

Comment: What is `C` ? could you explain?

Comment: Use a list. Something like this -> `cInstances = [container() for _ in range(4)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
class container():
    def __init__(self):
        pass


containers = {'C' + str(i): container() for i in range(1, 11)}
print(containers)
```

This will create ten container objects with key C1.. to C10

Answer (score 1):

Both lists and dicts allow you to group together the various containers to make it easier to maintain and use. Here's one way to do it.

```
class container():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

C_list = [container() for _ in range(4)] #using list
print(C_list)
#Output:
[<__main__.container at 0x278b1b451d0>,
 <__main__.container at 0x278b1b452b0>,
 <__main__.container at 0x278b1b45240>,
 <__main__.container at 0x278b1b45400>]
C_list[3]

C_dict = {f"C{i}":container() for i in range(1, 5)} #using dict
print(C_dict)
#Output:
{'C1': <__main__.container at 0x278b1b45748>,
 'C2': <__main__.container at 0x278b1b45780>,
 'C3': <__main__.container at 0x278b1b457f0>,
 'C4': <__main__.container at 0x278b1b45860>}

C_dict['C4']
```